# Animation in lottie crashes my react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lottie

I'm developing an application in React, the project was created with Vite.

I tried to implement an animation with Lottie and I succeeded, however, when I change the page (my application has 4 pages) where the animation is and I go back to that page, my site crashes.

I don't know what the problem is because it's my first time using Lottie in a project, any help is welcome.

Here is an example of a component that contains the animation:

```js
import { useLottie } from "lottie-react";

import devAnimationData from "../../assets/lottie/dev-animation.json";

export const Developer = () => {
  const styles = {
    height: 500,
    width: 500
  };

  const defaultOptions = {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    animationData: devAnimationData,
    rendererSettings: {
      preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice"
    }
  };
  const { View } = useLottie(defaultOptions, styles);
  return View;
};
```

Comment: Does it crash with an error message? If so, include that in your question

Comment: I'm having this exact problem...there is no error...

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same issue and after doing some research online I came across [this question](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/1702) in Github.

It seems like for some animations you may be loading the same animation object twice and this causes nested repeaters.

I followed the instructions given in *[bodymovin](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/1702#issuecomment-508553873)*'s comment and that seemed to fix the issue for me.

Instead of simply having animationData set the way you did I'd do the following:

```js
animationData: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(devAnimationData))
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

**The comment that I referenced to solve my issue:**

> *I guess animationData is being imported somewhere and passed down to this component every time you load an animation. If you pass the same
> animationData several times, you are passing the same object, and
> Lottie uses and modifies that object every time it loads a new
> animation. Repeatears, because of the way they work, create this type
> of nested elements and spike on memory. You probably should pass the
> animation data down by doing JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(animationData
> )) and it will work fine.*